# How to deploy IntelliJ IDEA project in Apache Tomcat server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, intellij-idea, web-deployment

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition . I have developed a Grails project in it . Can anyone tell me the steps to deploy this project in a remote Apache Tomcat server ?

Comment: At firts you should create WAR from your application. Then you could create Tomcat Remote run configuration and select your WAR artifact on the deployment tab. Also you could use Tomcat plugin in Grails (https://grails.org/plugin/tomcat) and default grails run/debug configuration.

Comment: if your project is in grails, simply you can add tomcat dependency and by creating war file you run as it is(Not required to deploy in Tomcat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to build a .war file of your project. 
`grails war`

(The .war file is in your Project path.)

Now you can deploy the .war file on your remote tomcat server. You copy the File in the `webapps` folder, then you can access on it: `http://localhost:8080/nameofyourwarfile`

If you have a problem you can check the log file: `logs/catalina.out`

http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/deployment.html

Comment: I just created a war file and copied it into the webapps folder of my tomcat . On starting the server my war file exploded and i was able to run my project . Thank You.